# Asymptotic behavior of truncated mean of zero mean variable

Tags: probability-theory, means

How do you show that 
$$\sqrt{n}\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[X\cdot \mathbb{1}_{|X|\leq\sqrt{n}}\right]\to 0$$

for a random variable $X$ with zero mean? Do we need finite variance?

Comment: Hint: Introduce $$X_n=\sqrt{n}\,X\,\mathbf 1_{|X|\gt\sqrt{n}},$$ then you try to show that $$E(X_n)\to0.$$ To apply Lebesgue dominated convergence, note that $X_n\to0$ almost surely and that, for every $n$, $$|X_n|\leqslant X^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it, I will write the answer later unless someone else wants to try.

Comment: This is a good option.